# What is the difference between sm.OLS and sm.Logit?

Tags: python, data-science, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I need to apply OLS regression to voting behavior data set. After analyzing my data I have concluded that I need to apply logistic regression. I have seen two method "sm.Logit" and "sm.OLS"? Both of these are for logistic regression?

Comment: OLS is for linear regressions, not logistic regressions.

Comment: So if in the question it ask to apply OLS regression it simply means to apply linear regression?